# Correct way to store uni/bi/trigrams ngrams in RDBMS?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, rdbms, n-gram

I have a list of unigrams (single word), bigrams (two words), and trigrams (three words) I have pulled out of a bunch of documents. My goal is a *statically analyses report* and also *a search* I can use on these documents.

```
John Doe
Xeon 5668x
corporate tax rates
beach
tax plan
Porta San Giovanni
```

The ngrams are tagged by date and document. So for example, I can find relations between bigrams and when their phrases first appeared as well as relations between documents. I can also search for documents that contain these X number of un/bi/trigram phrases.

So my question is how to store them to optimize these searches.

The simplest approach is just a simple string column for each phrase and then I add relations to the document_ngram table each time I find that word/phrase in the document.

```
table document
{
    id
    text
    date
}

table ngram
{
    id
    ngram varchar(200);
}

table document_ngram
{
    id
    ngram_id
    document_id
    date
}
```

However, This means that if I want to search through trigrams for a single word I have to use string searching. For example, lets say I wanted all trigrams with the word "summer" in them.

So if I instead split the words up so that the only thing stored in ngram was a single word, then added three columns so that all 1, 2, & 3 word chains could fit inside `document_ngram`?

```
table document_ngram
{
    id
    word1_id NOT NULL
    word2_id DEFAULT NULL
    word3_id DEFAULT NULL
    document_id
    date
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Are their better ways? I am currently using PostgreSQL and MySQL but I believe this is a generic SQL question.

Comment: The last version of "document_ngram" contains a repeating group. You'll need an extra table to avoid that. (the second version puts the repeating group inside a string, which is even worse)

Comment: @wildplasser, what do you mean by a "repeating group"?

Comment: 1NF: the word1_id, word2_id, word3_id are *in essence* an array.

Comment: You may have better results with non-relational database - have you considered this option?

Comment: I believe both Oracle and SQL server now offer special code for doing fulltext analysis. Google "Oracle Text" or "SQL Server Full-Text Search". PostGres has "Full Text Search" as well - see Chapter 12 of the PostGres manual.

Comment: This tutorial may be relevant, it uses `MySQL` and `R`: http://rpsychologist.com/how-to-work-with-google-ngram-data-sets-in-r-using-mysql/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I would model your data (note that 'the' is referenced twice) You could also add weights to the single words.

```
DROP SCHEMA ngram CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA ngram;

SET search_path='ngram';

CREATE table word
    ( word_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
    , the_word varchar
    , constraint word_the_word UNIQUE (the_word)
    );  
CREATE table ngram
    ( ngram_id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY 
    , n INTEGER NOT NULL -- arity
    , weight REAL -- payload
    );  

CREATE TABLE ngram_word
    ( ngram_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES ngram(ngram_id)
    , seq INTEGER NOT NULL
    , word_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES word(word_id)
    , PRIMARY KEY (ngram_id,seq)
    );  

INSERT INTO word(word_id,the_word) VALUES
(1, 'the') ,(2, 'man') ,(3, 'who') ,(4, 'sold') ,(5, 'world' );

INSERT INTO ngram(ngram_id, n, weight) VALUES
(101, 6, 1.0);

INSERT INTO ngram_word(ngram_id,seq,word_id) VALUES
( 101, 1, 1)
, ( 101, 2, 2)
, ( 101, 3, 3)
, ( 101, 4, 4)
, ( 101, 5, 1)
, ( 101, 6, 5)
    ;   

SELECT w.*
FROM ngram_word nw
JOIN word w ON w.word_id = nw.word_id
WHERE ngram_id = 101
ORDER BY seq;
```

RESULT:

```
 word_id | the_word 
---------+----------
       1 | the
       2 | man
       3 | who
       4 | sold
       1 | the
       5 | world
(6 rows)
```

Now, suppose you want to add a 4-gram to the existing (6-gram) data:

```
INSERT INTO word(word_id,the_word) VALUES
(6, 'is') ,(7, 'lost') ;

INSERT INTO ngram(ngram_id, n, weight) VALUES
(102, 4, 0.1);

INSERT INTO ngram_word(ngram_id,seq,word_id) VALUES
( 102, 1, 1)
, ( 102, 2, 2)
, ( 102, 3, 6)
, ( 102, 4, 7)
    ;   

SELECT w.*
FROM ngram_word nw
JOIN word w ON w.word_id = nw.word_id
WHERE ngram_id = 102
ORDER BY seq;
```

Additional result:

```
INSERT 0 2
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 4
 word_id | the_word 
---------+----------
       1 | the
       2 | man
       6 | is
       7 | lost
(4 rows)
```

BTW: adding a document-type object to this model will add two additional tables to this model: one for the document, and one for document*ngram. (or in another approach: for document*word) A recursive model would also be a possibility.

UPDATE: the above model will need an additional constraint, which will need triggers (or a rule+ an additional table) to be implemented. Pseudocode:

```
 ngram_word.seq >0 AND ngram_word.seq <= (select ngram.n FROM ngram ng WHERE ng.ngram_id = ngram_word.ngram_id)
```

Comment: Nice.  This is the right way to store the words so they're not duplicated and easy to query with.

Comment: Words are entities. Ngrams are entities. Documents are entities. The rest is relations between entities.

Comment: I'm trying to work through this. What is the weight column on the ngram table for? Since I need to link ngrams to documents would I add a document_ngram table that included a `date,ngram_word_id,document_id` and modify the `ngram_word` table to also have a primary key? Also, the `word_id` & `ngram_id` would be a SERIAL in real life right?

Comment: The weight-columns is unused payload, but I used it to show how attributes for ngrams could be stored (in most cases: weights or frequencies). The documents table is just another layer in the hierachy: a document refers to words and / or ngrams. Documents could also carry some summary information (such as validity, importance, ...)

Comment: And yes, word_id and ngram_id *could* be serials. (but they could also refer to a numbering which is imposed by another process outside your program / database)

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to modify your original table layout a bit.  Consider the ngram varchar(200) column to only contain 1 word of the ngram, add in a word_no (1, 2, or 3) column, and add in a grouping column, so that, for example the two records for the two words in a bigram are related (give them the same word_group).  [In Oracle, I'd pull the word_group numbers from a `Sequence` - I think PostGres would have something similar)

```
table document
{
    id
    text
    date
}

table ngram
{
    id
    word_group
    word_no
    ngram varchar(200);
}

table document_ngram
{
    id
    ngram_id
    document_id
    date
}
```